# How to solve two equations with two unknowns when exponent is very large

Tags: linear-algebra

How would you solve for $x$ and $y$?
$x+y=0$
$x(-3)^{10}+y5^{10}=1$

Comment: The second line is not complete. If it reads $x(-3)^{10}+y5^{10}=0$ there is only the trivial solution $x=y=0$.

Comment: @gammatester thanks I fixed it

Answer (score 2):

Your question is the same as asking where d lines $L_1(x) = Ax + C $ and $L_2(x) = Bx + D $ intersect? if they ever intersect, sometimes they don't, or sometimes they are just the same line. So, your question is equivalent to solve $L_1 = L_2 $ which occurs when

$$ Ax + C = Bx + D \implies x = \frac{D - C}{A - B } $$

GEOMETRY IS IMPORTANT! don't forget that.

As for your question, notice $A = -1, C = 0 $, $C = -3^{10}$, $D = 5^{10} $

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm really tired and shouldn't be mathing this late. Have a +1. :)

Comment: I thought you did not like geometry... hahah

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about the numbers until the very end. Do simple substitutions, but nothing more.

From the first equation, we know $y = -x$, so we substitute that into the second equation:
$$x \cdot 3^{10} - x \cdot 5^{10} = 1$$

Do you know what to do from here?

Comment: $=x(3^{10}-5^{10})=-9706576x=1$ therefore $x=\frac{1}{-9706576}$ is that right?

Comment: Downvoter: what did I mess up?

Comment: Yep, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

From the first equation we have $x=-y$. Substituting into the second we get
$$-y(-3)^{10}+5^{10} y = 1,$$ which on taking common factors gives $$y(5^{10}-(-3)^{10})=1.$$ Dividing we get the answer $$y=\frac{1}{5^{10}-(-3)^{10}}.$$ Substitute this back into the first equation to get $x$.